# Junit java.lang.OutOfMemoryError GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, junit, garbage-collection

I have the following `@Before` method for a JUnit test:

```
List<MyClass> allCombinations = new ArrayList<>();

@Before
public void generateCombinations() {
    int index = 0;
    char[] binaryChars = null;
    MyClass myMockObj = mock(MyClass.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 15); i++) {
        binaryChars = StringUtils.leftPad(Integer.toBinaryString(i), variables).toCharArray();
        when(myMockObj.method1()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method2()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method3()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method4()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method5()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method6()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method7()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method8()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method9()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method10()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method11()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method12()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method13()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method14()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        when(myMockObj.method15()).thenReturn(binaryChars[index++] == '0');
        allCombinations.add(myMockObj);
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

This method throws the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceededClose stacktrace
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
```

I understand from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom) what the error is. However, I don't know the reason in above code for getting this error.

Comment: If you change `Math.pow(2, 15)` to for example 10, then you would not get the error, right?

Comment: @Obviously, lesser that number, more chances I will stop getting error because the loop will run that many less number of times. How can I solve with power 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting feature of JUnit is that it creates an instance of the test class for each test case you run and those instances are not released for GC until all the tests have been run.

Thus, if you allocate a lot of data to instance variables in your test case (like in the generateCombinations method that  is run before every test) you have to manually release the data after the test.

Try adding a method

```
@After
public void cleanup() {
    allCombinations  = null;
}
```

We have made a tool that makes this automatically with reflection.

If cleaning up the test classes doesn't help, then you just need to throw more memory at it...

Comment: "An interesting feature of JUnit is that it creates...."  Isn't it supposed to be  like "An irresponsible bug of JUnit is that it creates..."

Comment: If it's creating a new instance every time and not cleaning up , then it's a bug in JUnit.. I heard this bug is fixed in latest versions but I am still getting this in Junit jupiter...